# Returning an entire item in an arrray containing a specific value

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string, variables

I'm trying to get an item in array which contains a specific value.

Let's say I have an array

```
var arr = ["boat.gif", "goat.png", "moat.jpg"];
```

And I have a variable `var imageName = "boat"`

Since I do not know the file extension of `imageName`, I need a way to run it through my array and get `"boat.gif"` as the output.

I tried this with regular expressions

```
let filesString = arr.join(" ");

let regExName = new RegExp(imageName, "i");

let fileName = regExName.exec(files­String),

file = fileName.input.subst­r(fileName.index, 5);
```

It works but I'm hoping there's a better way

I hope this makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be easier to filter by `.includes` or `.startsWith` instead:

```js
var arr = ["boat.gif", "goat.png", "moat.jpg"];
var imageName = "boat";

const found = arr.find(str => str.includes(imageName));
console.log(found);
```

or

```js
var arr = ["boat.gif", "goat.png", "moat.jpg"];
var imageName = "boat";

const found = arr.find(str => str.startsWith(imageName));
console.log(found);
```

If there might be other files in the directory which start with the same word (like `boats.gif`), then construct a regular expression like you're doing, but lookahead for a `.`:

```js
var arr = ["boat.gif", "goat.png", "moat.jpg"];
var imageName = "boat";

const pattern = new RegExp(imageName + '(?=\.)');

const found = arr.find(str => pattern.test(str));
console.log(found);
```

Comment: It solved my problem, do you mind sharing some articles or references to using array methods and regular expressions